# Zend Db Table Three tables JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework, join

```
1. payment(user_id, calculation_id)
2. user(id, user_name)
3. calculation(id, period_start_date, period_end_date)
```

I need to select `payments` with `user_name`, `period_start_date`, `period_end_date`. How can I do it within one query in Zend Framework?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found the solution:

```
$db     = new Zend_Db_Table('payment');
$select = $db->select()->setIntegrityCheck(false);
$select->from('payment')
       ->join('user', 'user.id = payment.user_id', array('user_name'))
       ->join('calculation', 'calculation.id = payment.calculation_id', array('period_start_date', 'period_end_date'));

$payment = $db->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
```